# CSS/PHP include() re-sizing a page

Tags: php, css

I have a page `graph.php` that creates a graph using Google Charts.

### Example

```
<div id="chart_div" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>
```

I visit `graph.php` directly and the graph is correctly displayed at 100% height and 100% width.

### Problem

I `include("graph.php");` this page in another page but the graph appears smaller. Is there a reason for this and how can I get it to be 100% width etc.?

### Code

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="graphs" style="width:100%"><?php include("chart.php"); ?></div>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP, the element under which you are including is not 100% wide.

Comment: This is CSS, not PHP.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's possible to be 100% in this element no problem, just tested it. Only the PHP `include()` is not working.

Comment: @user3636943 Say you have the graph 50% wide, you include in an element which is 50% wide, so your graph will be half of that 50% instead of 100%, hope you get my point, again, nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Your style="width:100%" applies to the div, that contains your graph div.

Something like this might work:

```
style="position:absolute;width:100%"
```

Answer (score 0):

does the parent element have any other styling? perhaps `padding`? Or like @Mr.Alien pointed out your parent element shows 100% width, but that is 100% of its own parent element.

In any case, when you view the included page on its own there are no parent elements surrounding it, but once you include it into your page there is "something" surrounding it in the form of parent element(s). Your problem is almost certainly in your CSS and one or more of the parent elements.